# How we can check the the variable text is number or not in Azure logic app without inline

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have variables `a = "hhddj";` Variable `b = "1234";`. I need an expression that gives a is type `string` and b is type `int`. Like we have `Isnumeric(a)` needs to return `false`, and `Isnumeric(b)` needs to return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression can be used for checking whether the text in `variables('a')` is in fact an integer:

`equals(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(variables('a'), '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''), '')`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the function called `isInt()` for example `isInt('10')` returns `true` , for more information please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#isInt